# join where field of same name is integer in one df and character in another

Tags: r, dplyr

```
glimpse(df1)
Observations: 10,772,215
Variables: 5
$ id                 <dbl> 17947442, 11919813, 11919814, ..
$ category_id        <int> 22, 6, 11, ...

glimpse(df2)
Observations: 3,000,000
Variables: 5
$ id                 <chr> "17947442", "11919813", "11919814", ..
$ blah        <int>  1, 2, 3, ...
```

I'd like to join df1 and df2 on id but id is a different type in each (dbl vs. chr).

Tried:

```
> newdf <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = c(as.character(id), id))
Error in as.character(id) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Then

```
newdf <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = "id")
Error in as.character(id) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Then

```
newdf <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = c(as.character(.$id), "id"))
Error in inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : Can't join on 'id' x 'id' because of incompatible types (numeric / character)
```

How can I join these? (Preferably using dplyr join)

Comment: why not just do: `newdf <- df1 %>% mutate(id = as.character(id)) %>% inner_join(df2, by = "id")`

Comment: Yes, that did it thanks!